# Python replicate each line and then make change in each line

Tags: python-3.5

I have a csv file which has lines like these:

`0.10089,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.8,-0.7,1999998.0,0,0,0,80,81.226,158.25,0`
`0.10955,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.5,0.4,-4.1,0,0,0,88.127,87.784,158.47,0`

I want to replicate each line 3 times, and then change the 4th element in each line`(1,2,...)` so that all lines(including the replicated lines) become part of this order

`0.10089,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.8,-0.7,1999998.0,0,0,0,80,81.226,158.25,0`
`0.10089,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.8,-0.7,1999998.0,0,0,0,80,81.226,158.25,0`
`0.10089,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.8,-0.7,1999998.0,0,0,0,80,81.226,158.25,0`
`0.10955,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.5,0.4,-4.1,0,0,0,88.127,87.784,158.47,0`
`0.10955,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.5,0.4,-4.1,0,0,0,88.127,87.784,158.47,0`
`0.10955,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.5,0.4,-4.1,0,0,0,88.127,87.784,158.47,0`

I know the index of each comma, and hence the position where the 4th element is

`with fileinput.input(inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        comma_pos_array = [i for i,x in enumerate(line) if x == ',']
        for i in range(3):
            print(line)`

I have tried approaches like making an array of consecutive integers from `0 to (number of lines in f)*3` and then changing the 4th element with the corresponding element in this new array, but they don't seem to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce exactly what you want (without csv module):

```
n = 1 # counter

for line in f:
    numbers = line.split(sep=',') # getting list of separated numbers
    for i in range(3):
        numbers[3] = n # replacing with proper value
        n += 1
        s = ''
        for i in numbers: # adding commas
            s += str(i) + ','
        s.rstrip(',') # removing last comma
        print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a variant using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) to read and write the in/output:

```
from io import StringIO
from csv import reader, writer

txt = '''0.10089,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.8,-0.7,1999998.0,0,0,0,80,81.226,158.25,0
0.10955,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.5,0.4,-4.1,0,0,0,88.127,87.784,158.47,0'''

REPEAT = 3

with StringIO(txt) as infile, StringIO() as outfile:

    rows = reader(infile)
    out_csv = writer(outfile)

    counter = 0

    for row in rows:
        for i in range(REPEAT):
            counter += 1
            row[3] = counter
            out_csv.writerow(row)

    print(outfile.getvalue())
```

and produces the output:

```
0.10089,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.8,-0.7,1999998.0,0,0,0,80,81.226,158.25,0
0.10089,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.8,-0.7,1999998.0,0,0,0,80,81.226,158.25,0
0.10089,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.8,-0.7,1999998.0,0,0,0,80,81.226,158.25,0
0.10955,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.5,0.4,-4.1,0,0,0,88.127,87.784,158.47,0
0.10955,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.5,0.4,-4.1,0,0,0,88.127,87.784,158.47,0
0.10955,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.5,0.4,-4.1,0,0,0,88.127,87.784,158.47,0
```

(you need to replace the `StringIO` parts with your files; i used them here to make the example self-contained)